# How to get all the Debian CD ISO files to Blu-ray

Tags: debian, debian-lenny

There is a machine running Lenny without raid. It does pose a problem in case of HDD failure. Safety plan was like this: Install Lenny on clean disk of same properties, then copy/replace all the backed-up files from previous disk over the freshly installed Debian. It should work, at least I was told so while ago.

But I only have netinst of Debian Lenny. My best guess, there won't be working mirrors for old Lenny anymore. I thought about downloading full installation upfront, being ready, but it's 31 ISO files. I can't really imagine feeding them all to machine, when I'm in hurry to get the machine back to work.

**Is there any blu-ray/USB stick version or other way to install debian from single spot? (all the files have to be on drive)** All I was able to found so far is 31x CD ISO files and I'm not sure if it's even possible to repack that on different medium.

Comment: You generally only need CD1. You probably ought to test it. Also, running an old, unsupported version of an OS is a *horrible* idea.

Comment: Why don't you make a real backup of the machine that doesn't need this kind of nonsense? And why are you still running Lenny anyway?

Comment: @SvW Is there any way to make an system image from within the running system itself? That's sound like bad idea. Maybe take the HDD out of the machine and make copy, but I would prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`jigdo`](https://wiki.debian.org/jigdo) for instance you can see that latest Debian stable, Wheezy has Jigdo image templates for such purpose [here](https://www.debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/)